Why is the condition $\mathbf{P}\left(H_{t-1} \cap\left\{X_t=x\right\}\right)>0$ at the definition of markov property
In the book of David A. Levin, it states that

A sequence of random variables $\left(X_0, X_1, \ldots\right)$ is a Markov chain with state space $\mathcal{X}$ and transition matrix $P$ if for all $x, y \in \mathcal{X}$, all $t \geq 1$, and all events $H_{t-1}=$ $\bigcap_{s=0}^{t-1}\left\{X_s=x_s\right\}$ satisfying $\mathbf{P}\left(H_{t-1} \cap\left\{X_t=x\right\}\right)>0$, we have
$$
\mathbf{P}\left\{X_{t+1}=y \mid H_{t-1} \cap\left\{X_t=x\right\}\right\}=\mathbf{P}\left\{X_{t+1}=y \mid X_t=x\right\}=P(x, y) .
$$

However, I cannot understand, nor can I find a counterexample, for why the markov property needs to be satisfied only by $x,y,H_{t-1}$ that satisfies $\mathbf{P}\left(H_{t-1} \cap\left\{X_t=x\right\}\right)>0$.
I would appreciate any help.

$\mathbf{P}\left(H_{t-1} \cap\left{X_t=x\right}\right)>0$ is just the assumption that the history up to time $t-1$ is some particular  $x_t$

It is needed for the conditional probabilities to exist, as according to Bayes theorem, $$P(A \vert B) = \dfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}, \text{ if } P(B) > 0$$
Also, notice that $P(H_{t - 1} \cap \{X_t = x\}) \le P(X_t = x)$, thus, by having $P(H_{t - 1} \cap \{X_t = x\}) > 0$, both conditional probabilities
$$
    P(X_{t + 1} = y \vert H_{t - 1} \cap \{X_t = x\}) \text{ and } P(X_{t+1} = y \vert X_t = x)
$$
exist
